# AngularJS: promise not correctly resolved

Tags: angularjs, promise, deferred

I have a strange behaviour of my promise. See following plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/uBuBS3Oi7mIPob2jtqkm

It is based on plunk of a very good article from Marc Galgleish (http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/).

In my controller I have a simple $scope attribute named messages (getting a defer object from the service):

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {
  $scope.messages = HelloWorld.getMessages();

  $scope.click = function()
  {
    alert($scope.messages[0]);
  }
});
```

As expected, after the promise is fulfilled (per resolve) the view gets the actual values and is showing them. But clicking on the button and executing the click function, I cannot use the $scope.messages as expected. The promise is not resolved there, just in the view.

With (http://plnkr.co/edit/vX3dSFjzB6R7q4Oed7Gj)

```
HelloWorld.getMessages().then( function(data){
  $scope.messages = data;
});
```

everything works fine, but that's not a solution for me. In my real application it's a service returning either a complex already synchronized, cached object (from local storage) or a promise if synchronization with the server is required. Return after synchronization the updated object.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance
Knut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise is still a promise even after it is resolved.

Try this:

```
$scope.click = function()
{
  $scope.messages.then(function(msgArray) {
    alert(msgArray[0]);
  });
}
```